# javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory and javax.xml.validation.Schema Thread Safety

Tags: java

What is the best way to make the below thread safe besides synchronizing SchemaFactory.newInstance and SchemaFactory.newSchema?  This logic is behind a Spring based REST API.

```
private boolean isXMLValid(String XSDPath, String XML) {
            final SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            try {
                final Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(XSDPath));
                final Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
                validator.validate(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(XML.getBytes())));
            } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem here? This code is thread-safe.